# Who takes the hit?

Tags: dark-souls

In a ongoing round of Dark Souls: The Board Game, my family and I hit a disagreement. It's basically regarding whether or not the enemy can change priorities in the middle of their turn.

[image: turn 1]

The sentinel in the center node has their turn as such: Move to nearest person (with the push effect) followed by attacking the nearest person.

In this situation the nearest person is the warrior so, the sentinel moves to the warrior and pushes them to a different node.

[image: turn 2]

Now is when the attack happens (which targets nearest player) and this is where the argument kicks in. The warrior and assassin are now at equal distances from the sentinel but the assassin has the aggro token. **Would the sentinel attack the first person it targeted or would it now attack the assassin because they have the aggro token?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Not just *can*, but *must* change, if the facts have changed.

Per page 24 of the rulebook,

> All behaviour icons are resolved from left to right.

That is, you resolve the movement icon, and then you resolve the attack icon separately. The priorities are checked when they should apply, not "carried over" from a previous action, unless this is explicitly stated in a rule or behaviour icon.

The "nearest character" should be evaluated **after** the movement is complete and the attack is to begin.

Per page 25 of the rulebook,

> If two or more characters are tied as nearest, the enemy attacks the character with the aggro token.

The assassin and the warrior are tied for nearest. The next check is for the aggro token, which the assassin has, so they are the target.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree...In the same rule (Page 24)

> If the enemy movement covers multiple nodes, determinate the nearest character AT THE START of the movement, not at each step.

And like in the "behaviour icons" of the Sentinel never appears the aggro icon you dont have to be guided by the aggro token but by the START of your movement...